# Programmatically find indexes that cannot be rebuilt online

Tags: sql-server, index, t-sql

I am automating rebuild and reorganise indexes using T-SQL. I run into problems with indexes that cannot be rebuilt online. Primarily this happens because ntext/nvarchar columns are included.

Is there a way to programmatically identify them as part of this statement? So kind of addition to the WHERE predicate

```
SELECT 
--TOP 20
OBJECT_NAME(IPS.OBJECT_ID) AS [TableName], avg_fragmentation_in_percent, SI.name         [IndexName],  
schema_name(ST.schema_id) AS [SchemaName], 0 AS IsProcessed 
INTO #FramentedTableList 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL , NULL) IPS 
JOIN sys.tables ST WITH (nolock) ON IPS.OBJECT_ID = ST.OBJECT_ID 
JOIN sys.indexes SI WITH (nolock) ON IPS.OBJECT_ID = SI.OBJECT_ID AND IPS.index_id =   SI.index_id 
WHERE ST.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND SI.name IS NOT NULL 
AND avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= CONVERT(DECIMAL,   @FragmentationThresholdForReorganizeTableLowerLimit) 
ORDER BY avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this to your `WHERE` clause to leave out any indexes that include a LOB type (I think I captured them all):

```
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM sys.index_columns AS ic
  INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
  ON ic.object_id = c.object_id
  AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
  AND ((c.system_type_id IN (34,35,99,241)) -- image, text, ntext, xml
   OR (c.system_type_id IN (167,231,165) -- varchar, nvarchar, varbinary
       AND max_length = -1))
  WHERE ic.object_id = SI.object_id
  AND ic.index_id = SI.index_id
)
```

If you're using SQL Server 2008 or 2008 R2, you can change the type search to the following in order to capture `geography` and `geometry` (credit [Kenneth Fisher](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41650/1186)):

```
  AND ((c.system_type_id IN (34,35,99,241)) -- image, text, ntext, xml
   OR (c.system_type_id IN (167,231,165)    -- varchar, nvarchar, varbinary
       AND max_length = -1)
   OR (c.user_type_id IN (129,130)))        -- geometry, geography
```

Of course, it may be smarter to restructure your query so that you rebuild the indexes you can online, and don't leave those that you can't out of your maintenance altogether. But I agree with Max, don't reinvent the wheel. Go get Ola's scripts or, if you want something much more robust, please let me know.

Comment: I like your answer since it actually answers the question.  Good advice overall too!

Comment: Thanks all. I've used this method for now. I've looked at Ola's scripts. The problem I was originally grappling with was massive log bloat during index rebuild, so I'm trying an approach of rebuilding the 20 worst indexes at a time - I couldn't figure out how to incorporate this into Ola's script just yet.

Answer (score 3):

I use the following to detect LOBs:

```
SET @LOBCount = (
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        select t.name as TableName, i.name as IndexName, c.name as ColumnName, ty.name, ic.is_included_column
            from [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.indexes i 
            INNER JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.tables t ON t.object_id = i.object_id 
            inner join [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.index_columns ic on i.object_id = ic.object_id and i.index_id = ic.index_id
            inner join [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.columns c on ic.object_id = c.object_id and ic.column_id = c.column_id
            INNER JOIN [' + @DatabaseName + '].sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id
            where 
                t.name = ''' + @TableName + '''  
                AND i.name = ''' + @IndexName + '''
                AND (
                    ty.name IN (''text'', ''ntext'', ''image'')
                    or 
                    (
                        ty.name IN (''varchar'', ''nvarchar'', ''varbinary'', ''xml'') 
                        AND c.max_length = -1
                    )
                )
        ) as x
    )';
```

Obviously, this is a code fragment from a much larger stored proc that we use to rebuild and/or reorganize indexes.  I would recommend you look at Ola Hallengren's scripts at:  http://ola.hallengren.com/

Answer (score 3):

Specifically look at the NOT EXISTS in the WHERE clause.

```
SELECT 
--TOP 20
OBJECT_NAME(IPS.OBJECT_ID) AS [TableName], avg_fragmentation_in_percent, 
    SI.name [IndexName],  schema_name(ST.schema_id) AS [SchemaName], 
    0 AS IsProcessed 
INTO #FramentedTableList 
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(), NULL, NULL, NULL , NULL) IPS 
JOIN sys.tables ST WITH (nolock) 
    ON IPS.OBJECT_ID = ST.OBJECT_ID 
JOIN sys.indexes SI WITH (nolock) 
    ON IPS.OBJECT_ID = SI.OBJECT_ID AND IPS.index_id =   SI.index_id 
WHERE ST.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND SI.name IS NOT NULL 
AND avg_fragmentation_in_percent >= 
        CONVERT(DECIMAL, @FragmentationThresholdForReorganizeTableLowerLimit) 
AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1 
        FROM sys.index_columns
        JOIN sys.columns
            ON sys.index_columns.column_id = sys.columns.column_id
            AND sys.columns.object_id = sys.index_columns.object_id
        JOIN sys.types
            ON sys.types.system_type_id = sys.columns.system_type_id
        WHERE sys.index_columns.index_id = SI.index_id -- Join to get the correct index
            AND sys.index_columns.object_id = ips.object_id -- Join to get the correct table
            AND (sys.types.name IN ('text','ntext','xml','image','geometry','geography')
                OR  (sys.types.name IN ('varchar','nvarchar','varbinary')
                    AND sys.columns.max_length = -1) -- means MAX
                )
            )
ORDER BY avg_fragmentation_in_percent DESC
```